# pip install . not installing updated package

Tags: python, build, pip, package, shared-libraries

I have a python package, `opensource`, that i modified on my local development environment. When I run `pip install .` within the directory of that package, everything updates and it works fine.

However the issue happens when i `scp` the directory over to my virtual machine. Before I copy over, on the VM I do `pip uninstall opensource` followed with `rm -r opensource` to remove that package. After I copy it over, I do `pip install .` and it says that the package was installed, however when I run my python files it calls the old build version of the package instead of the one I copied over.

How can I copy over my modified package and have it run the new version?

Comment: can you run `which opensource`. this should give you which version is in use.

Comment: Ran it and nothing appeared